# How to print out columns instead of rows?

Tags: java, arrays

alright so im making a program that prints out how many times the numbers 0-9 were input, its supposed to go on forever, until the user types a negative number, then its gonna stop the program and print out the result, heres my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class opg33 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(1 + ":" + "\t" + "Integer 0-9");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] a = new int[10];
        int counter = 0;
        int input;
        input = keyboard.nextInt();
        boolean exit = true;

        while (exit == true) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println((counter + 1) + ":" + "\t" + "Integer 0-9");
            if (input > -1 && input < 10) {
                a[input]++;
            }

            input = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (input < 0) {
                exit = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(i + ":");
                    for (int n = 0; n < a[i]; n++)
                        System.out.print("x");
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see this program works perfectly fine, just as I wanted it to! the only question I have, is, how can I make it print out vertically like a bar graph (columns), instead of horizontally? thanks in advance!

Comment: It becomes significantly more difficult.  You cannot just output to the console directly.  You need to loop over all of the items in the list and print all of the results row by row.  Start by printing the largest one and then the largest and second largest etc until you reach the bottom of your graph.  This sounds a lot like homework so I will leave the implementation up to you.

Comment: Approach 1: Instead of using `System.out.print`, set up a 2-dimensional array of characters, initialize them to `' '`, then put `x` into the array.  Then go through vertically and print the array.  Approach 2: If the largest number in `a` is, say, 10, then print `x` for every number where `a[n]==10`, then on the next line, print `x` for every number where `a[n]` is 9 or 10, then 8, 9, or 10, etc.

Comment: hmm what do you mean? I make a 2-d array one for the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and the other for the times it was input?

Comment: if your histogram can start from top to bottom, like negative values, it's even easier IMO.

Comment: hmm yeah, idk im clueless, might have to do that if thats easier, idk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like...?

```
1:    Integer 0-9
1
2:    Integer 0-9
1
3:    Integer 0-9
2
4:    Integer 0-9
2
5:    Integer 0-9
2
6:    Integer 0-9
3
7:    Integer 0-9
3
8:    Integer 0-9
7
9:    Integer 0-9
8
10:    Integer 0-9
-1
       x                      
    x  x  x                   
    x  x  x           x  x    
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

The first thing you need to do is determine the max height of the chart...

```
// Calculate the required height...
/*
   All this loop does, is loops through the array "a"
   and finds the maximum value contained within,
   this is the largest number of times the user
   entered that value

   The loop itself is just an enhanced "for-next-loop", 
   that is, it's a short cutted way of saying...

   for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
       int value = a[index];
       ...
   }
*/
int maxFrequency = 0;
for (int value : a) {
    // This is a really simply way to calculate the max value within 
    // range, it just says, return me the value which is the larger
    // of two...
    maxFrequency = Math.max(value, maxFrequency);
}
```

Next, you need to print each row of the chart, starting at the top and moving to the bottom.  For each column, you need to determine if it has a value to be displayed within that row...

```
// This builds each row
for (int row = maxFrequency; row > 0; row--) {
    // This is used instead of String concatenation (String + String)
    // This is the preferred mechanism for doing String concatenation
    // in loops as it uses less memory and will generally be faster...
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(30);

    // We need to inspect each value in the array to determine
    // if we need to display something...
    // The basic idea is, we will only start displaying "x"
    // when the value in the array >= the row number...
    for (int value : a) {
        // This just appends each column value as
        // required, prefixing and suffixing it with spaces
        sb.append(" ");
        if (value >= row) {
            sb.append("x");
        } else {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    // Print the row...
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

And finally, you need to print the footer...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(30);
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sb.append(" ").
            append(i).
            append(" ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

**The hows and why of `StringBuilder`**

A book could be written on this subject, so the information provided here is just an overview...

`StringBuilder` should be used, especially, when concatenating `String`s in loops,   basically because it reduces the number of temporary, short lived objects that are created and makes the process more efficient.

Normally the Java compiler will convert `String` concatenation to use `StringBuilder` internally, but because of the nature of loops, can't do so.  In your case, it's probably not all that important, but in long running programs which might iterate through the loop, hundreds, thousands or even millions of time, it becomes a performance bottleneck, so it is a good habit to form.

Internally, a `StringBuilder` is a self managed `char` array, this is not particular important, but it's nice to know.  When you use `.append`, the `StringBuilder` is taking the content, making space for it within it's internal buffer and writing out the content to it.  It might sound like that's introducing it's own overheads and to a certain extent it is (you can do things to imittergate these), but it's less then having to run a garbage collection cycle...

`toString` simply then converts the `char` array to a `String` object...

You can find more information at [The StringBuilder Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

Comment: thanks a lot, can you explain a bit on stringbuilder thing and append, tostring etc? and this for-loop thing is just so you dont have to make new variable and ++ and all that all the time?